# Android - Buttons are "following" other buttons in layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, android-relativelayout

why are my buttons "following" other buttons in the layout (xml) file? I take the first button (button1) and if I move it, the second button (button2) follows the first... I figured out that if I change the position of the 2 buttons in the right section of Eclipse (if I move button1 under button2 under the group of RelativeLayout) it continues.. What can i do???

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/check"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:onClick="audio"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:onClick="wifi"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:onClick="teleph"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:onClick="nfc"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:onClick="touch"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:onClick="bluet"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_data_bluetooth" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="img"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:onClick="camera"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

[image]

Comment: Post your xml. Probably due to the properties you are using (i.e. `android:layout_below=""`. It is much easier to use the xml tab, IMHO, than to try and use the graphical view

Comment: just posted the code... yes, but if i remove android:layou_below="" then i have to reposition the button and if i reposition it, this lines autoadds...

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to move one but not the other? A graphical representation of what you want might help also.

Comment: Cannot post a graphical representation because it wouldn't be necessary.. alredy posted xml

Comment: It would be to help you move your `Views` to where you want them so you can learn how to use the xml properties better. Or a description of what you want. If you move them then the properties are of course going to change. I didn't mean just that one but you have others that are dependent on other `Views` as well

Comment: I need that 2 buttons are on 1 line

Comment: Below the `TextView`? You have a lot of `Buttons`.

Comment: yes. I can'tpost image because i don't have reputation

Comment: i have 8 buttons... 2 of them every single line

Comment: check here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/dv7m.png/

Comment: That's what you have now?

Comment: yep... i need that all buttons are like the last 2. Thank you codeMagic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to wrap each set of `Buttons` in a `LinearLayout` and use the property `android:layout_below="@id/layoutIdAbove`

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
  <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/LL1"
       ...
       android:layout_below="@id/textView1"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:onClick="audio"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off"
         />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:onClick="wifi"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL2"
    ...
    android:layout_below="@id/LL1">
   <! -- add next two Buttons and repeat  -->
```

Comment: Why the first times i used eclipse it didnt' happen?

Comment: You're welcome! I can't say without knowing the circumstances. Maybe you weren't using certain properties, were using a different `ViewGroup`, etc... I don't use the graphical view except to confirm that my xml changes are what I want. Its much easier to use xml